# App Installation Failed: App has disallowed Info.plist key

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9

Just recently I've run into errors while trying to install my app to my iOS 9 device, only difference that I can tell between now and then being I've updated my device to iOS 9 from iOS 8.4.1.

I'm installing using Xcode 7, beta 6, and the error I get says "App installation failed: Unknown error."

The, I suspect, more helpful error message I get is from the device logs during the install, the error message that seems to pertain to this is:

```
Sep 14 13:10:47 Bill-Luhmanns-iPhone installd[50] <Error>: 0x16e1bb000 -[MIExecutableBundle hasOnlyAllowedWatchKitAppInfoPlistKeysWithError:]: 1033: WatchKit app has disallowed Info.plist key: CFAppVersion
```

Then there are a handful of other logs that give the same message from different areas.

Any ideas how I can get the target to allow that key in the plist file? I've checks that the file is in the right place, that the key exists, etc. etc. As a last ditch effort, I've deleted my derived data and restarted both mac and device, all to no avail. Cleaning the project also didn't help.

Any suggestions or ways to fix this that anyone is familiar with? I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: First thing I would do is update to Xcode 7 GM.

Comment: I had the same thought, I'm downloading that now. I was able to build it to the device when I ran an older branch that hasn't been updated in a while, so I'm hoping the GM of Xcode 7 works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's saying the info.plist associated with your watch kit app has an invalid key - CFAppVersion. I think you'll discover that deleting that key from your watch kit app's info.plist will fix your build issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using healthKit and added Privacy keys in watch target's info.plist.

Removing those keys and adding in app target's Info.plist resolved the error.