# WatchKit NSAppTransportSecurity error

Tags: ios, swift, plist, watchkit

I get this error when I run my project:

[image]

I have read a lot of questions but these don't helped me to solved my issue. In fact, I have set the value of `App Transport Security Settings` to YES (like in my screenshot) in both of my iOS app and watchOS extension.

[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you set `App Transport Security Settings` to NO? or do you need it as all? I found something here, this might help with your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571265/app-installation-failed-app-has-disallowed-info-plist-key

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be disallowed for the "watchkitapp"-target itself. You are still able to add the ATS-Key to the `Info.plist` of the "watchkitapp-extension"-Target.

You should be able to define a exception-domain like this:

[image]